# How to enter localhost url manually ( using xampp php version 7.2)

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am trying to get into my root i have xampp in my D folder and i have create folder name (app) into my htdocs and created file Book.php now i am trying to access this file using url http://localhost/app/Book.php but no output. can anyone correct me?

```
class Book // class is where we define properties and methods
         {

public $isbn;
public $title;
public $author;
public $available;



//instantiate

$harry_potter = new Book();
$harry_potter->isbn = 322401494;
$harry_potter->title = "Harry Potter and Magicians";
$harry_potter->author = "Shahzad";
$harry_potter->available = 10;
var_dump($harry_potter);
```

Comment: can you confirm that the server is running?

Comment: yes server is running

Comment: I got this when i run in brower: Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can see 2 main reasons for this to happen,

- You aren't using the right port, XAMPP might be using another port like 8080 check it out in the settings. If this is right then you should access to your file using localhost:port/book.php
- Book.php return nothing, you should post book.php code here so we can figure out where is the problem.

Hope it could help.

Comment: i am just doing it myself

Comment: my port is localhost:80

Comment: port is displaying 80, 443

Comment: Maybe you should try localhost:443/book.php

Comment: i have Book.php in my app directory

Comment: object not found!

Comment: Assuming you copy/pasted your code, you are missing an "}", on the other side, it looks like the original problem got solved. If you get an "objet not found" that mean  it did loaded, the problem here is in your .php in my opinion.